# Assign values based on rows count

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count

I have a live order pickup case where below constraints are needed to be met

1. if 0 < Orders(rows) <=4, give each row with time value "4am"
2. if 4 < Orders(rows) <=10, give minimum 4 rows with "4am" and remainder rows with "6pm"
   3, if Orders(rows) >10, additional time value "12pm" will be added and distribute rows evenly as close as possible with value "4am", "12pm", "6pm"

[image]

I was only able to write condition when counted rows are less than or equal to 4 but had hard time figuring it out when row count was greater than 4

```
pos = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If pos <= 4 Then Range("B" & i).Value = "4AM"
```

Comment: Why can't you write a second condition?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do here.  Given this set of data, do you expect to see CDF, CVG, HJI, and IKL give a value of 4 AM and RED give a value of 6 PM?  Or does the presence of RED mean all the previous data get a value of 6 PM as well?

In English, is CDF an order that came in early, so it will be picked at 4 AM, or is CDF part of a five-item order, and because it's a larger order, it needs to be picked at 6 PM?

If the latter, try this:

```
Sub Test()
    i = 1
    pos = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    Do While i <= pos
        If pos <= 4 Then
            Range("E" & i).Value = "4AM"
        Else
            If pos <= 10 Then
                Range("E" & i).Value = "6PM"
            Else
                Range("E" & i).Value = "12PM"
            End If
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I think what he meant is , if the total orders ar less than 4 , al the order are to be picked up at 4 am, if the are more than 4 but less or equal to 10, the first 4 will be set at 4 am and the rest at 6pm and the last case, if the total orders are more than 10, you split the orders in 3 groups as equal as possible and assign to each group the 3 possible pick up times

Comment: that is exactly what I meant to address! My apologizes fellas if I did not explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

`This will assign pickup as desired:

```
Public Sub Orders()
    pos = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1 'Subtract the header line
    
    If pos <= 4 Then
        Range("B2:B" & pos + 1).Value = "4AM"
    ElseIf pos <= 10 Then
        Range("B2:B5").Value = "4AM"
        Range("B6:B" & pos + 1).Value = "6PM"
    Else
        Dim ordersPerRange As Long: ordersPerRange = Int(pos / 3)
        Range("B2:B" & (ordersPerRange + 1)).Value = "4AM"
        Range("B" & (ordersPerRange + 2) & ":B" & (ordersPerRange * 2 + 1)).Value = "12PM"
        Range("B" & (ordersPerRange * 2 + 2) & ":B" & (pos + 1)).Value = "6PM"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it works wonder just as I wanted it to. thank you so much sir!